# How to enable one-tap delete of photos in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos

How do I enable one-tap delete of photos in iPhone?  Right now I have to tap twice: first, the trash icon, and second the "Delete Photo" confirmation.

I just want to tap the trash can icon to delete the photo.

[image]

I found a similar question on Apple Community [Deleting photos using a single tap](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8442291) but there's no reply.

Comment: Most likely there is no reply because no such option exists. Maybe you can create a shortcut to delete without a prompt, but running that would need two taps (and some scrolling) as well.